# HTML form mailto: Mail body is empty, no matter what got filled out

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to make a simple html form, that can then be sent as a Mail on submitting.
Here's some example code from w3docs.com:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <style>
      div {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Give Feedback to Our Website.</h2>
    <form action="mailto:info@w3docs.com" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
      <div>
        <label for="name">Name:
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email:
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Comments:</label>
        <br />
        <textarea name="comments" rows="12" cols="35">Send your comments to us.</textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear Form" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, this should open the mail client with a prefilled mail for info@w3docs.com. However, the mail always ends up being empty.

Since this is copied code, that should work, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: `mailto:` supports a `body` parameter, not `comments`… https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto

Comment: Note that the `<input>` and `<br>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<textarea name="body" rows="12" cols="35">Send your comments to us.</textarea>
```

By using GET parameters you can play with the subject or the body by doing so:

```
mailto:info@w3docs.com?body=whatever&subject=whatever
```